# Post data back to server using Knockout mapping

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, webforms, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've bind list of objects to check boxes list using KnockoutJs and KnockoutJs Mapping Plugin, with this code

**Server Side Class**

```
public struct FilterListItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var dto = { 'categoryId': getUrlVars()["scid"] };

    $.ajax({
        url: "ProductListTest.aspx/GetFiltersWeb",
        data: JSON.stringify(dto),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "JSON",
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function (result) {
            bindFilterModel(result);
        }
    });
});

function bindFilterModel(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var jsonObject;
    jsonObject = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    var viewModel = { CategoryList: jsonObject.d };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: CategoryList.SubCategoryList">
    <div class="line">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: Value" /><span data-bind="text: Text"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I need to post user selected data to a WebMethod (with a Ajax call), when a user selected a checkbox, but I can not figure out how to bind event to trigger the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RP's dirty plugin

http://jsfiddle.net/df6z6/

```
ViewModel = function(data) {    
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
    this.dirty = ko.dirtyFlag(this.items, false);
    this.dirty.isDirty.subscribe(this.onDirty, this);
};

ViewModel.prototype = {
    onDirty: function() {
        console.log("Post here");
        this.dirty.reset();
    }
};
```